# Replace line in file during multiple threads

Tags: c#

I have a small csv file with about 40 lines of 30-ish characters each. I also have several slow threads going at the same time, so they will rarely attempt to access the file at the same time, however it can happen. So I need to make sure that they all wait for turn if necessary.

As I understand I can do:

```
string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(path);
text[23] = "replacement";
File.WriteAllLines(path, text);
```

But doing this I assume I'm running the risk of the file being updated by a different thread in between readAllLines and WriteAllLines.

What I want to do is something like:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    //Replace the line
}
```

However I don't see a way to do something like writeAllLines with either the FileStream object or the StreamWriter object. Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to write each line to a new file and then replace the old file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `StreamWriter` you don't need to specify to write all lines. You just write what you have. Either write to the file line by line using the `WriteLine` method or join your text array into one large string and write it all at once using the `Write` method.

As for preventing multiple threads from accessing your file at the same time you should use a lock.

```
public static object FileAccessLock = new object(); // Put this in a global area.

lock(FileAccessLock)
{
    string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    text[23] = "replacement";
    File.WriteAllLines(path, text);
}
```

The lock will allow only one thread to access that section of code at a time. All other threads will wait until it has completed.

That doesn't mean that the `File.WriteAllLines` method wont be locked by something else so you should handle an exception here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock write to only one thread access. 
Like this:

```
public class FileHelper
{
    private static object fileLock  = new object();
    public static void ReplaceLine(string path, int line, string replace)
    {
        lock(fileLock)
        {
            string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            text[line] = replace;      
            File.WriteAllLines(path, text);
        } 
    } 
}
```